# C++ program crashes when reading from text file?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am making a program that reads in a string of numbers from a text file and uses those numbers to create a polynomial. I am using a linked list to create the polynomial. Each node in the list represents a term in the polynomial. The nodes have data members such as coefficient and exponent and obviously a pointer that will point to the next node (term). I don't know what is wrong with my code, but when I try to read from the text file my program crashes. I know that my program can find the file (it's in the same project directory) but as soon as I type in the name and press enter it stops running. Here is my code.

```
#include "polynomial.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>       // for exit() call

using namespace std;


void makePolynomials( shared_ptr<Polynomial> [], int *x );


int main()
   {
   shared_ptr<Polynomial> poly[ 100 ];
   int nPolynomials;

   makePolynomials( poly, &nPolynomials );

   // print out the polynomials
   // -------------------------
   for (int j=0; j < nPolynomials; j++)
      cout << *(poly[j]);

   return 0;
   }



void makePolynomials( shared_ptr<Polynomial> poly[], int *nPolynomials )
   {
   // get the filename from the user and open the file
   // ------------------------------------------------
   char filename[50];
   cout << "Enter the filename: ";
   cin >> filename;

   ifstream infile;
   infile.open( filename );
   if (! infile.is_open()) {
      cerr << "ERROR: could not open file " << filename << endl;
      exit(1);
      }

   // read in the data and construct a polynomial for each input line
   // ---------------------------------------------------------------
   string polynom;
   while (getline( infile, polynom ))
      {
      poly[ *nPolynomials ] = shared_ptr<Polynomial>(new Polynomial( polynom ));
      nPolynomials++;
      }
   }
```

class Polynomial constructor

```
    Polynomial::Polynomial( string & str )
   {
   stringstream ss( str );  // stringstream lets us extract items separated by
                            // whitespace simply by using the >> operator
   double coefficient;      // to hold the coefficient
   int exp;                 // to hold the exponent
   head = nullptr;          // initialize head to null

   // read in coefficient-exponent pairs and add each term to the list
   // ----------------------------------------------------------------
   while (ss >> coefficient >> exp)
      if (coefficient != 0)   // don't make a 0 term
         head = shared_ptr<Term>(new Term( coefficient, exp, head ));
   }
```

Comment: What do you think is the value of *nPolynomials at the start of the loop that reads the lines?

Comment: @immibis is it null?

Comment: no, it's exactly what you set it to (hint: you didn't set it to anything). Note: not the pointer itself, but the thing it points to.

Comment: @immibis This was such a stupid mistake, I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the following line is causing the problem:

```
   int nPolynomials; //contains a garbage value
```

Make it :

```
  int nPolynomials=0; // or initialise it to any other value
```

Comment: thank you for pointing this out. I can't believe I didn't realize that earlier.

Comment: could you explain to me what shared_ptr<Polynomial> poly [100] does?

Comment: std::shared_ptr is a smart pointer that retains shared ownership of an object through a pointer. Several shared_ptr objects may own the same object. The object is destroyed and its memory deallocated when either of the following happens

Comment: <polynomial>is the vector

Comment: poly[100] creates 100 of the shared_ptr<Polynomial> and stores in an array called poly